# How to read a file containing two columns of numbers then returning the average of each column?

Tags: java, string

I want to read a file containing two columns of floating-point numbers. Then i want to print the average of each column.

There are 2 columns with numbers - in other words, there are 2 numbers in each row. Here is an example:

File contains:
7 3
5 2
9 11
10 12

The output should be:
Average for column 1 is 7,75
Average for column 2 is 7

I have this code so far:

```
public class MainApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String fileName = "columns.txt";
        double number = 0;
        File file = new File(fileName);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                number = number + Integer.parseInt(scanner.next());
                number = number / 2;
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: And your code doesn't do what? I guess you didn't intend to have us mentally executing your code in order to find out what the problem is?

Comment: So what is the problem with your code? Is it not working? How does your input file look like?

Comment: You never reset number to 0.

Comment: Hi, please clarify what the problem is- it is not clear what are you asking, also if you will provide the example of the file, it will be nice, thanks in advance

Comment: Please only use `Scanner#next` and his friends if you know exactly how it works (internal token buffer etc). I would recommend everyone to just use `Scanner#nextLine` all the time, or learn how the methods work. Misusage of the class is one of the most common mistakes beginners make.

Comment: What do you mean by "the average of each column"? If the input has 20 lines of two columns each, do you want the output to be 20 numbers (each being the average of the two columns on each line) or do you want 2 numbers, being the average of all numbers in column 1 and the average of all numbers in column 2?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException - The question was not clear enough, I have updated the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you expect double output, then it's better to parse the numbers to double, not int.

You can use `String.split` to split the line on white spaces and then parse the doubles:

```
double first = 0.0;
double second= 0.0;
int lines = 0;

if (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = line.split("\\s+"); // split on white spaces
    first += Double.parseDouble(numbers[0]);
    second += Double.parseDouble(numbers[1]);
    lines++;
}
if (lines > 0) {
    System.out.println(first / lines);
    System.out.println(second / lines);
}
```

Comment: @BasilBattikhi probably because it attempts to answer a question that is not clear yet. This answer e.g. assumes that the input file contains two double numbers in decimal format delimited by white spaces. Afaik one should ask for clarification instead of making an answer based on assumptions so that the actual question is answered.

Comment: @Ben i guess the question is clear enough to be answered
He said two columns so he answered it in happy scenario there are no special characters between those columns and if there are, the question owner should edit this answer in order to meet his requirement otherwise he is not a developer.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the output the OP wanted. He asked for "the average of each column", not the "average of the two columns on each line". I left a comment asking the OP for clarification.

Comment: Sorry the question was not clear enough - I have updated the question

Comment: @user3740970 Updated the answer.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether `line` should be trimmed before splitting, in case the numbers are right-justified (which would then make `numbers[0] == ""`). Or is there a regex for `split()` which would deal with this? What do you think?

Answer (score -2):

I changed the while-loop. Now the values of the two columns are read in one statement and assigned to a variable number and divided by two.
The original code computed the average value each time a value was read and never resetted the number-variable.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String fileName = "columns.txt";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        double number = (Integer.parseInt(scanner.next()) + Integer.parseInt(scanner.next())) / 2.0;
        System.out.println(number);
    }
    scanner.close();

}

}
```

Comment: Please add some description about what did you do explain something not just putting an answer