# How can I read int and string (two columns) from file in Java?

Tags: java, file, readfile

I have a file with two columns:

```
10 Mike
7 Jhon
21 Charles
```

and I wanted to read these values. Is there an easy wy to do this? I know in C++ it's simple, but it seems it's not in Java.

Comment: [`java.util.Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) makes it simple in Java too.

Comment: yes, there is an easy way. What have you tryed, and what didn't work?

Comment: You should check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50330203/how-to-read-a-file-containing-two-columns-of-numbers-then-returning-the-average) answer

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways you can do it. If you use Java 8+, you can do:

```
Files.readAllLines(...)
    .forEach(line -> {
       String[] splitted = line.split("\\s+");
       //now you can access your values splitted[0] and splitted[1]
    });
```

You can convert the string values to the type you want afterwards.

You can also use libraries for more complex scenarios. Some common ones are:

1. Apache Commons CSV https://www.baeldung.com/apache-commons-csv
2. Jackson CSV https://dirask.com/posts/Java-how-to-read-CSV-file-into-java-object-using-Jackson-CSV-library-complex-example-with-BigDecimal-and-enum-x1Rm7j

Answer (score 0):

Use a Scanner object to Input data from a text file

Instantiate the object:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("example.txt"));
```

Call Method for Next Integer in the File

```
int n = scan.nextInt();
```

Call Method for next String

```
String s = scan.next();
```